# Standard Machinery to prove this result

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu$ be a measure on a measurable space and $K_1, K_2$ be markov kernels satisfying
$$
\mu \otimes K_1 (A\times B) = \mu\otimes K_2(B\times A) \qquad \text{for any } A, B \text{ measurable.}
$$
I would like to show that this **equivalent** to the fact that for any measurable functions $f, g$
$$
\mu\otimes K_1(f\times g) = \mu \otimes K_2(g \times f)
$$
or in other words
$$
\int f(x) g(y) \mu(dx) K_1(x, dy) = \int f(y)g(x) \mu(dy) K_2(y, dx)
$$

## Attempt

I tried using the standard machinery. First, the assumption is
$$
\int_A \mu(dx)  K_1(x, B) = \int_B \mu(dy) K_2(y, A)
$$
which can also be written in terms of indicator functions
$$
\int_{X^2} 1_A(x) 1_B(y) \mu(dx) K_1(x, dy) = \int_{X^2} 1_A(x) 1_B(y) \mu(dy) K_2(y, dx)
$$
then my guess is that I could then say that this holds for simple functions and then for measurable functions, by using the Monotone Convergence Theorem. However I have not encountered a problem with this product structure and I am not sure if it would apply.

Comment: I am using the convention that for a measure $\nu$ and a function $f$ I write 
$$
\nu(f) = \int f \, d\nu
$$
I am also using the convention that for a measure $\nu$ and a kernel $K$, $\nu\otimes K$ is the joint measure
$$
(\nu \otimes K)(dx\times dy) = \nu(x) K(x, dy)
$$
which more formally means
$$
(\nu\otimes K)(A\times B) = \int_{A\times B} d( \nu\otimes K) = \int_A \nu(dx) K(x, B)
$$
The backward implication is easy, just take $f=1_A$ and $g=1_B$. But I am interested in the other direction, which probably requires the standard machinery.

Comment: Throughout I am assuming the existence of a measurable space $(X, \mathcal{X})$. I am also assuming $\mu:\mathcal{X}\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is a finite measure (possibly a probability measure). The kernels are $K_1, K_2:X\times\mathcal{X}\to [0, 1]$ meaning they are Markov Probability kernels, although finite Markov kernels are probably enough. I am also assuming $A, B\in\mathcal{X}$.

Comment: **First Step** Let $A_1, \ldots, A_N$ be measurable sets. Then I want to show that 
$$
\int_{X^2} 1_A(x) 1_B(y) \mu(dx) K_1(x, dy) = \int_{X^2} 1_A(x)1_B(y) \mu(dy) K_2(y, dx)
$$
implies
$$
\int_{X^2}\left\{\sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i 1_{A_i}(x)\right\}1_B(y) \mu(dx)K_1(x, dy) = \int_{X^2}\left\{\sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i 1_{A_i}(x)\right\}1_B(y) \mu(dy)K_2(y, dx)
$$
for coefficients $\alpha_i\in\mathbb{R}$. As long as I can exchange integral and sum, this should be true.

Comment: **Second Step**: Take the limit as $N$ goes to infinity and use Monotone Convergence Theorem. Hopefully that means that one can replace $1_A(x)$ with any measurable function $f(x)$, so one would get
$$
\int_{X^2} f(x) 1_B(y) \mu(dx) K_1(x, dy) = \int_{X^2} f(x) 1_B(y) \mu(dy) K_2(y, dx)
$$
Then do the same for $1_B$.